# How to disable syntax warning for the latest sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have updated the latest Sublime Text 3 build (3124), but when I save the changes of python file, the warning will shown as below:

[image]

I installed the [Python Flake8 Lint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Flake8%20Lint) package, but the warning is never shown for old sublime version.

How to disable it?

Comment: I suspect that the new `show_errors_inline` option does this; try setting that to `false`. Or switch to `SublimeLinter` with `SublimeLinter-flake8` (I don't see this and that's the linter I use, though they do plan to implement support).

Comment: I also see a `"popup"` option on the Python Flake8 Lint package documentation (*popup a dialog of detected conditions?*) which defaults to `true`. Perhaps set that to `false` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I add show_errors_inline option to syntax specific setting, then reinstall the Python Flake8 Lint package, then is ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the `show_panel_on_save` setting by setting it to "never".

**Menu > Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings**

Or use the Command Palette: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> and select: **Preferences: SublimeLinter Settings**

```
{
    // Show the output panel on save if there are problems.
    // - window: check if the window has problems.
    // - view: only check the current file.
    // - never: disable this feature.
    "show_panel_on_save": "never"
}
```

### Older versions of SublimeLinter

Disable the `show_errors_on_save` setting.

**Menu > Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings**

```
{
    // This setting determines if a Quick Panel with all errors is   
    // displayed when a file is saved. The default value is false.
    "show_errors_on_save": false
}
```

Or use the Command Palette to disable it:

1. Open the Command Palette: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>
2. Select: `SublimeLinter: Don't Show Errors on Save`
3. Done!

Comment: I am not able to suppress the warning alone. They dont show up when i run flake8 on the console. igore=["D101"] does not work either(on Flake8Lint.sublime-settings). Thanks for the help.

Comment: This does not work for me; the property `show_errors_on_save` does not exist, I have turned `show_panel_on_save` to `never` instead, but the panel still appears on save... any other ideas?

Comment: @Leonard In newer versions of SublimeLinter the setting is `show_panel_on_save`. I've updated the answer with steps for the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `Python Flake8 Lint` package installed. In that case, just go to

<kbd>Menu</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> >  <kbd>Package Settings</kbd>  > <kbd>Python Flake8 Lint</kbd>  > <kbd>Settings - User</kbd>

add the following lines to the file, and save the file:

```
    {
        "popup": false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference from https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-turn-off-the-red-error-boxes-shown-inline-in-code-when-building/23736

To add a line:

```
"show_errors_inline": false
```

[image]